# Force Result on Query IF true

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT cust.adm, COUNT(visits.visit_date) as visit_count FROM cust
LEFT JOIN visits ON cust.cust_id = visits.cust_id
WHERE cust.cust_id = 1
GROUP BY cust.adm
```

the results are:

```
   adm   |   visit_count
--------------------------
  TRUE   |        0
```

Is there a way to force a result of '3' on 'visit_count' IF the adm is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT    cust.adm,
          CASE cust.adm WHEN TRUE THEN 3 ELSE COUNT(visits.visit_date) END AS visit_count 
FROM      cust
LEFT JOIN visits ON cust.cust_id = visits.cust_id
WHERE     cust.cust_id = 1
GROUP BY  cust.adm
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

This is really forcing it. Not knowing what you're trying to achieve this is all I can think of.

```
SELECT cust.adm, 
    CASE WHEN cust.adm THEN 3 ELSE COUNT(visits.visit_date) END as visit_count
FROM cust
    LEFT JOIN visits ON cust.cust_id = visits.cust_id
    WHERE cust.cust_id = 1
    GROUP BY cust.adm
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed!